# mongodb: automatically sync embedded documents

Tags: mongodb, nosql

I'm new to mongo so pls bear with me here

From what I understand, one of the biggest advantages of mongo is that it gives us the **option** to embed related documents, leading to fast and simple reads at the cost of write speed.

This makes total sense, but the question then becomes how can I easily keep multiple embedded documents in sync if they're used in more than 1 collection.

So let's say we had **posts** that embedded **authors**, and also **groups** that embedded **authors**. And say authors did not change much, so we decided to embed the authors in both posts and groups. Now when an author changes their name for example, you'd have to go update all their posts and all the groups they were in.

Surely there's an abstraction that could handle this for us, so that we could just update a central authors table posts and groups would automatically be updated. Does such an abstraction exist? or am I missing something

Comment: With the authors, and groups and posts with authors - when an author's name changes there are couple of scenarios. Say, if the posts have the author id embedded (or rather referenced) then only the author collection changes. But, if you have author id and name stored in the posts. then you may have to update the posts document also with changed name. This kind of not-so-often changes can be batched as an end-of-day process, for example.

Comment: Also refer this: https://www.mongodb.com/docs/v5.0/core/data-modeling-introduction/